# JavaScript Double Assignemnt

Tags: javascript, express

What's the purpose of double assignment in ExpressJS and what exactly does it do? Here is an example of the code below from an ExpressJS example.

```
var app = module.exports = express()
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply is a shortcut to setting two variables or objects at the same time. So instead of writing...

```
var exp = express();
var app = exp;
module.exports = exp;
```

you can write it on one line...

```
var app = module.exports = express()
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value to two different things. In this case, the `exports` property to make it available outside the module, and the `app` variable so it has a short name by which it can be referred inside the module.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the function call is assigned to both `module.exports` and `app` …

In JavaScript, the result of an assign expression is always the assigned value, so `module.exports = express()` is evaluated first, and then the result of that expression is assigned to `app`.